# Controller Setup for Rails Has Many Through Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, has-many-through

I have a similar question to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219559/multiple-associations-to-same-model). I'm a newbie and have been reading up for several hours on how to get this answer but haven't been able to get to the answer, so many thanks for the assistance! I have followed the answer from Kikito to setup the following models: Users, Photos, Locations, Photo_Relationships. My routes file contains:

```
resources :users 
resources :locations do
  resources :photos
end
resources :photo_relationships
```

I'm able to get the photo to save to the correct Location in my application, but I'm unable to assign multiple Users (specifically the creator of the Photo) to the Photo via the Photo_Relationships model.

```
class CreatePhotoRelationshipsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :photo_relationships do |t|
        t.integer :photo_id
        t.integer :user_id
        t.integer :role_id

        t.timestamps
    end
```

**Photos Controller**

```
  def create
    @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
    @photo = @location.photos.new(params[:photo])
    @photo.create_photo_relationship(@photo, current_user, 0)
    if @photo.save
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully added your photo"
        redirect_to [@mountain, @photo]
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

**Photo_Relationships Controller**

```
def create
  @relationship = photo_relationships.new(params[:photo][:location])
  @photo.create_photo_relationship()
end
```

My current error is undefined method `photo_relationship'. Whatever help or direction someone is able to offer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class is `PhotoRelationship` not `photo_relationships`.

Your controller line should read:

```
@relationship = PhotoRelationship.new(params[:photo][:mountain])
```

Comment: Thanks Max for your response. I switched this one out and have a slightly different error now: Expected app/models/photo_relationship.rb to define PhotoRelationship. (I also switched around the create photo relationship code to build.)

Comment: What is the class declaration of `app/models/photo_relationship.rb`? It should say `class PhotoRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base`.